# Starting Gunicorn Service in Dockerfile : Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gunicorn, systemd

I m trying to start services(gunicorn, nginx) with my dockerfile but I got that error.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y --enablerepo=base clean metadata
RUN yum -y install nginx
RUN yum -y install python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN yum -y install systemd;
RUN yum clean all;

COPY . /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN ./manage.py makemigrations
RUN ./manage.py migrate

ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

#Gunicorn
RUN cp gunicorn_systemd  /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
RUN systemctl start gunicorn
RUN systemctl enable gunicorn
```

And this is my build command

> docker build -t guni ./

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to interact with `systemd` in your build script:

```
RUN systemctl start gunicorn
```

There are a number of problems here.  First, trying to "start" a service as part of the build process doesn't make any sense: you're building an image, not starting a container.

Secondly, you're trying to interact with `systemd`, but you're never starting `systemd`, and it is unlikely that you want to [1].  Since a docker container is typically a "single process" environment, you don't need any init-like process supervisor to start things for you.  You just need to arrange to run the necessary command yourself.

Taking Apache `httpd` as an example, rather than running:

```
systemctl start httpd
```

You would run:

```
httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

This runs the webserver and ensures that it stays in the foreground (the Docker container will exit when the foreground process exits).  You can surely do something similar with gunicorn.

Your container is also missing a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` directive, so it's not going to do anything when you run it unless you provide an explicit command, and that's probably not the behavior you want.

[1] If you *really* think you need systemd, you would need to arrange to start it when the container starts (e.g, `CMD /sbin/init`), but `systemd` is not something that runs well in an unprivileged container environment.  It's possible but I wouldn't recommend it.